# Additive functors and zero homomorphisms

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

The question:

Let $F:\mbox{Ab} \to \mbox{Ab}$  be an additive functor; if $f$ is a zero homomorphism, then so is $F(f)$; if $A$ is the zero group, then so is $F(A)$.

This boils down to showing that, for an additive functor $F(0)=0$. Obviously this is true, but my category theory is very basic, and I can't quite yet get a handle on what is allowed.

Is it simply just the case that

$$F(f+g)=F(f)+f(g) \implies F(0) = F(f+(-f))=F(f)+F(-f)=F(f)-F(f)=0?$$

Comment: You would need to show that $F(-f) = -F(f)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition an additive functor induces homomorphisms on the hom-groups, that is
$$
\begin{array}{c}
\mbox{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(A,B) \to \mbox{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(FA,FB)\\
f \mapsto F(f)
\end{array}
$$ 
is an homomorphism. And well, homomorphisms preserve the neutral element.

Notice that $\mbox{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(A,B)$ is a group with the point-wise operation inherited from $\mathbb Z$. Therefore the neutral element is the $0$ morphism